# Access Regular Gmail Account with API in Lambda

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I want to create a simple service that periodically checks my gmail in search for bank transactions. My objective is to turn this into a simple app for other users eventually, but for now I just want it to work with my regular gmail account.

I enabled access to Gmail API with OAuth client and used the `credentials.json` to retrieve mails. This works as a first and manual approach but it needs to change because it requires my authorization in a browser and this will be a problem since the lambda code will run in a server without my intervention. I read that it is recommended to use a Google Service Account to access but this only works for workspace accounts.

Is there a way to make this work?